# VisualFlow - Field Lookup

Tags: lookup, visual-workflow

I'm creating a flow and was wondering if there exists the capability to lookup records on the input screen. On the standard record creation page, some fields have a lookup icon, shown in the screenshot below. I know that I can use the Record Lookup to validate that an entry exists, but ideally I would be able to select a value from a lookup screen.

[image: Magnifying glass lookup icon on Account Name field]

In my specific scenario, I am creating opportunity and lead records from within a flow, and would like to have the ability to lookup certain fields directly from that screen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create dynamic choices but it would be in the form of a radio button or select list not a lookup, there is a great blog [here](http://www.buttonclickadmin.com/salesforce-visual-workflow-advanced-flows/) on advanced flows by Mike Gerholdt if you need an example of how to create them. Otherwise, I believe you would need to try to combine visualforce with the flow.

> Creating dynamic choices can be one of the most powerful functions of
>   Visual Workflow.  A dynamic choice allows you search for records, then
>   display the returned data to the end user in a picklist, or radio
>   buttons to select.  Once that is record is selected, you can then take
>   the ID, as well as any other information from that record and store
>   into different variables to use within your Flow.